# Is there any way to track link clicks for the links sent through SMS in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

We want to send product links to contacts through SMS. Once they click on the link we want them to follow a different path in journey. I am not able to add engagement split after SMS message in journey. What could be the way to track the links clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it through a small workaround which tells me whether link was clicked or not by adding True as a value for a field in DE against that record.
For this, you can create a landing page with only AMP script using Lookup function which will find you record within DE using SubKey (URL needs SubKey as QueryParameter). Then use Update Data to update the checkbox field to True against that record.Also, use Redirect function in the page to a desired Web Page you want user to navigate too.

Answer (score 3):

May I point you to this discussion right here:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000p7XYQAY

The functionality is not available with standard SMS messages. However there are hints in there how to accomplish this.

Comment: There is an Idea in the coomunity for this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CMoCQAW